# Regex for all 10 letter words, with unique letters

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to write a regex that will display all words that are 10 characters long, and none of the letters are repeating.

So far, I have got

```
grep --colour -Eow '(\w{10})'
```

Which is the very first part of the question. How would I go about checking for the "uniqueness"? I really don't have a clue, apart from that I need to use back references.

Comment: This must be done with a regex?

Comment: I am practising regex, so preferably yes :)

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with a computer-science style regular expression: what you want requires "memory" of what the preceding matched characters are, and regular expressions just don't have that. That said, you might be able to do it with back references and the non-regular-expression things that PCRE-style matching can do.

Comment: I think this can be done with negating backreferences in grep, eg: `grep  '^\(.\)\(^\1\)\(^\2\)\(^\3\)\(^\4\)\(^\5\)\(^\6\)\(^\7\)\(^\8\)\(^\9\)$' /usr/share/dict/words` but somehow negating backreference is not working for me.

Comment: @Ketan, surely you would have to do it in a character set. `grep -E '(.)[^\1]'` would be the way to get a non-repeated character, but the back references are not accepted in a character set.

Comment: @Graeme yep, that is where I started. But switched back thinking backrefs are themselves considered character sets. Apparently not.

Comment: @goldilocks Agreed. If it is at all possible, the pattern will be an eyesore and a most _irregular_ expression.

Comment: @Ketan, a `^` outside of a set has a different meaning - it matches the start of a line.

Comment: @Ketan Even if it were possible (and I have not seen any evidence of that), negating backreferences isn't the answer. `[^\1]` will also match whitespace and punctuation. You need to subtract `\1` from `\w` or `[A-Za-z]` depending on what you mean by "word".

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that `\w` will match an `_`, which isn't really part of a word as most define it.

Comment: @Graeme, that is almost correct, just negate it with `grep` option, not inside the expression: `grep -Ev '(.).*\1'`.

Comment: @Joseph, you would have to use two regex's. One like your Q to match words and another to exclude repeated characters. This is enough of a regex abuse I think!

Comment: @manatwork, that only works for two unique characters though. It needs to be extendible to 10.

Comment: @Graeme, I supposed this will be just the second half of the solution. `<input grep -Eow '\w{10}' | grep -Ev '(.).*\1'`.

Comment: @Ketan See my answer if you're interested.

Comment: @BruceEdiger as long as there are a finite number of characters in the language (26) and letters in the string (10), its quite possible to do.  Its just a lot of states, but nothing that would make it not a regular language.

Comment: Do you mean "All English words ..."? Do you mean to include those spelled with hyphens and apostrophes or not (in-law, don't)? Do you mean to include words such as café, naïve, façade?

Comment: @BruceEdiger (and remembering this a bit later) you might be interested in the [Levenshtein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata) which when built from a given string can match all strings that have a Levenshtein distance of less than N.  And in doing this, it has a 'memory' of what letters have already been matched.  A similar automata can be constructed for this case too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
grep -Eow '\w{10}' | grep -v '\(.\).*\1'
```

excludes words that have two identical characters.

```
grep -Eow '\w{10}' | grep -v '\(.\)\1'
```

excludes the ones that have repeating characters.

POSIXly:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' |
   grep -xE '.{10}' |
   grep -v '\(.\).*\1'
```

`tr` puts words on their own line by converting any <kbd>s</kbd>equence of non-word-characters (<kbd>c</kbd>omplement of alpha-numeric and underscore) to a newline character.

Or with one `grep`:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' |
   grep -ve '^.\{0,9\}$' -e '.\{11\}' -e '\(.\).*\1'
```

(exclude lines of less than 10 and more than 10 characters and those with a character appearing at least twice).

With one `grep` only (GNU grep with PCRE support or `pcregrep`):

```
grep -Po '\b(?:(\w)(?!\w*\1)){10}\b'
```

That is, a word boundary (`\b`) followed by a sequence of 10 word characters (provided that each is not followed by a sequence of word characters and themselves, using the negative look-ahead PCRE operator `(?!...)`).

We're lucky that it works here, as not many regexp engines work with  backreferences inside repeating parts.

Note that (with my version of GNU grep at least)

```
grep -Pow '(?:(\w)(?!\w*\1)){10}'
```

Doesn't work, but

```
grep -Pow '(?:(\w)(?!\w*\2)){10}'
```

does (as `echo aa | grep -Pw '(.)\2'`) which sounds like a bug.

You may want:

```
grep -Po '(*UCP)\b(?:(\w)(?!\w*\1)){10}\b'
```

if you want `\w` or `\b` to consider any letter as a word component and not just the ASCII ones in non-ASCII locales.

Another alternative:

```
grep -Po '\b(?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)\w{10}\b'
```

That is a word boundary (one that is not followed by a sequence of word characters one of which repeats) followed by 10 word characters.

Things to possibly have at the back of one's mind:

- Comparison is case sensitive, so `Babylonish` for instance would be matched, since all the characters are different even though there are two `B`s, one lower and one upper case (use `-i` to change that).
- for `-w`, `\w` and `\b`, a word is a letter (ASCII ones only for GNU `grep` [for now](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37600), the `[:alpha:]` character class in your locale if using `-P` and `(*UCP)`), decimal digits or *underscore*.
- that means that `c'est` (two words as per the French definition of a word) or `it's` (one word according to some English definitions of a word) or `rendez-vous` (one word as per the French definition of a word) are not considered one word.
- Even with `(*UCP)`, Unicode combining characters are not considered as word components, so `téléphone` (`$'t\u00e9le\u0301phone'`) is considered as 10 characters, one of which non-alpha. `défavorisé` (`$'d\u00e9favorise\u0301'`) would be matched even though it's got two `é` because that's 10 all different alpha characters followed by a combining acute accent (non-alpha, so there's a word boundary between the `e` and its accent).

Comment: Awesome. `\w` does not match `-` though.

Comment: @Stephane Can you post a brief explanation of last two expressions.

Comment: Sometimes it seems like lookarounds are the solution to all the things that used to be impossible with RE.

Comment: @Barmar they're still impossible with Regular Expressions.  A "Regular Expression" is a mathematical construct that explicitly only allows certain constructs, namely literal characters, character classes, and the '|', '(...)', '?', '+' and '*' operators.  Any so-called "regular expression" that uses an operator that is not one of the above is not actually a Regular Expression.

Comment: @Jules This is unix.stackexchange.com, not math.stackexchange.com. The mathematical RE's are irrelevant in this context, we're talking about the kinds of REs you use with grep, PCRE, etc.

Comment: I still think the terminology is important.  A PCRE or an Extended POSIX RE or whatever other variant you may choose to use is different to a standard RE, and there are several contexts in which that difference can be important.  A regular expression using only the standard operators can be processed with a memory requirement that grows linearly with the length of the expression itself, whereas matching a PCRE with a backreference against a stream can require a theoretically unlimited quantity of memory.

Comment: @Jules, note that the back-references are in standard basic regular expressions (and have been over 3 decades), while they're not in standard (POSIX) extended regular expressions. Note that those regexps are matched against lines, not the full stream.

Comment: A line has a potentially unlimited length, though.

Comment: @Jules : I think you erased your preliminary comment which is a shame, because the `O(N)` *time* complexity of "classical" regular expressions is a worthwhile point to make.  However, it might be better to say that regular expressions that don't confine themselves to that specific set of operators have an indeterminate complexity rather than saying they "aren't regular expressions".  In this case, it's of course impossible: this is minimally an `O(N log N)` complexity operation. *[BTW you actually referred to "memory usage" in your comment, but it's **time,** not space complexity.]*

Comment: Hmmm, sorry that should be `O(N^2)`.  And you didn't erase anything, I was just confused by the ordering of comments when I looked back.  So "memory requirement that grows linearly" should be "linear time complexity".  The memory requirement (space complexity) for any regular expression of any kind (classical or not) will be `O(N)` -- i.e., memory use is not significant here.

Comment: @Jules The language to be matched is finite. That is certainly possible with pure regular expressions, though neither a good course of action nor interesting.

Answer (score 13):

Okay...here's the clunky way for a five character string:

```
grep -P '^(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3|\4).$'
```

Because you cannot put a back reference in a character class (e.g. `[^\1|\2]`), you must use a *negative look-ahead* -- `(?!foo)`.  This is a PCRE feature so you need the `-P` switch.

The pattern for a 10 character string will be a lot longer, of course, but there is a shorter method using a variable length anything match ('.*') in the lookahead:

```
grep -P '^(.)(?!.*\1)(.)(?!.*\2)(.)(?!.*\3)(.)(?!.*\4)(.)(?!.*\5).$'
```

---

After reading Stephane Chazelas's enlightening answer, I realized there is a similar simple pattern for this usable via grep's `-v` switch:

```
    (.).*\1
```

Since the check proceeds one character at a time, this will see if any given character is followed by zero or more characters (`.*`) and then a match for the back reference.  `-v` inverts, printing only things which *don't* match this pattern.  This makes the back references more useful since they can't be negated with a character class, and significantly:

```
grep -v '\(.\).*\1'
```

will work to identify a string of any length with unique characters whereas:

```
grep -P '(.)(?!.*\1)'
```

will not, since it will match whatever suffix with unique characters (e.g. `abcabc` matches because of `abc` at the end, and `aaaa` because of `a` at the end -- hence *any* string).  This is a complication caused by lookarounds being zero-width (they do not consume anything).

Comment: Well done! This will only work in combination with the one in the Q though.

Comment: I believe you can simplify the first one if your regex engine allows variable-length negative lookahead: `(.)(?!.*\1)(.)(?!.*\2)(.)(?!.*\3)(.)(?!\4).`

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig : Absolutely, nice call.  I've add that in.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to do the whole thing in regex, I would do it on two steps: first match all 10-letter words, then filter them for uniqueness. The shortest way I know how to do this is in Perl:

```
perl -nle 'MATCH:while(/\W(\w{10})\W/g){
             undef %seen;
             for(split//,$1){next MATCH if ++$seen{$_} > 1}
             print
           }' your_file
```

Note the additional `\W` anchors to ensure that only words that are exactly 10 characters long are matched.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like it as a regex oneliner :)

Answer (score 4):

Others have suggested this is not possible without various extensions to certain regular expression systems that are not in fact regular. However, since the language you want to match is finite, it's clearly regular. For 3 letters from a 4-letter alphabet, it would be easy:

```
(abc|abd|acb|acd|bac|bad|bcd|bdc|cab|cad|cbd|cdb|dab|dac|dbc|dcb)
```

Obviously this gets out of hand in a hurry with more letters and larger alphabets. :-)

Comment: I had to upvote this because it's actually an answer that would work. Though it might actually be the least efficient way anyone has written regex ever :P

Answer (score 4):

Option `--perl-regexp` (short `-P`) of GNU `grep` uses more powerful regular expressions that include look ahead patterns. The following pattern looks for each letter that this letter does not appear in the remainder of the word:

```
grep -Pow '((\w)(?!\w*\g{-1})){10}'
```

However the run-time behavior is quite bad, because `\w*` can have nearly infinite length. It can be limited to `\w{,8}`, but that also checks beyond the word limit of 10 letters. Therefore the following pattern first checks the correct word length:

```
grep -Pow '(?=\w{10}\b)((\w)(?!\w*\g{-1})){10}'
```

As test file I have used a large ≈ 500 MB file:

- First pattern: ≈ 43 s
- Latter pattern: ≈ 15 s

**Update:**

I couldn't  find a significant change in the run-time behavior for a non-greedy operator (`\w*?`) or possessive operator (`(...){10}+`). A tiny bit faster seems the replacement of option `-w`:

```
grep -Po '\b(?=\w{10}\b)((\w)(?!\w*\g{-1})){10}\b'
```

An update of grep from version 2.13 to 2.18 was much more effective. The test file only took ≈ 6 s.

Comment: Performance will depend a lot on the nature of the data. When doing tests on mine, I found that using non-greedy operators (`\w{,8}?`) helped for some type of input (though not very significantly). Nice use of `\g{-1}` to work around the GNU grep bug.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thanks for the feedback. I had also tried non-greedy and possessive operators and have not found a significant change in the run-time behavior (version 2.13). Version 2.18 is much faster and I could see at least a tiny bit of improvement. The GNU grep bug is present in both versions. Anyway I prefer the relative reference `\g{-1}`, because it makes the pattern more independent on the location. In this form it can be used as part of a larger pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'print if (!/(.)(?=$1)/g && /^\w{10}$/)' file
```

but it doesnt work with

```
perl -lne 'print if (!/(.)(?=\1)/g && /^\w{10}$/)' file
```

or

```
perl -lne 'print if ( /(.)(?!$1)/g && /^\w{10}$/)' file
```

tested with perl v5.14.2 and v5.18.2

Comment: The 1st and the 3rd does nothing, the 2nd outputs any line of 10 or more characters, with no more than 2 consecutive spaces. http://pastebin.com/eEDcy02D

Comment: it is probably the perl version. tested with v5.14.2 and  v5.18.2

Comment: I tried them with v5.14.1 on Linux and v5.14.2 on Cygwin. Both behaved like in the pastebin sample I linked earlier.

Comment: the first line works for me with the noted versions of perl. the two latter should work, because they are the same re, but didn't . perlre note often that some greedy expressions are highly experimental.

Comment: Retested with your latest updates. Only the 2nd one outputs correctly. (However the word must be alone in a line, while the question is about matching words, not entire lines.)

Comment: interesting and not affirmative